# Python multiplication Matrix with Matrix transpose with array

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy

[1]: https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/3/0/a/30aed0153521807d5a314ea76f37e723.png [1].

I want to write the above equation in Python using numpy functions:

```
b = b - INV(J'*J) * J' * r(b)
```

J is matrix , J' the  matrix transpose of J, 
X and r arrays

```
b = b  - linalg.inv((zip(*J)).dot(J)).dot(zip(*J)).dot(r)
```

this is not working... any suggestion?

EDIT

error:

```
AttributeError: 'zip' object has no attribute 'dot'
```

,...
I use Python 3.2

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to what is not working?  Is the result incorrect, or is python throwing some sort of error?  If an error is thrown, please edit your post by copying and pasting the error into the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `zip` because other posts about how to transpose a list of lists in python recommend using this.  This is not what you are using... you are using `numpy`, so you want to use the `.T` attribute which returns the transpose of your array.  Additionally, `dot` is a numpy function, not a method of a nmpy array:

```
b = b - np.dot(np.dot(linalg.inv(np.dot(J.T, J)), J.T), r(b))
```

Comment: thank you ... but , I get the error : "ValueError: expected square matrix" ... I need this : INV(J'*J) * J' * r(b) ... as you have write it, is not the same , right?

Comment: Nope.  That's not how I wrote it.  What is `r(b)`?  That looks like a function.  In the meantime I'll clean up the equation.

Comment: let say that r(b) is an array R ... how I  have to write that?

Comment: @user1972847 Just make an array `R` and replace `r(b)` with `R` in my answer.

Comment: @SethMMorton You wrote "Additionally, dot is a numpy function, not a method of a n[u]mpy array" --- well, dot is a numpy function but it's also a method of numpy arrays, as in
`a=np.zeros((4,2));print a.T.dot(a)`
that gives me

 [[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]